# Internal error AsyncOperationConflictException when trying processing Azure Analysis Service

Tags: azure, api, azure-logic-apps, azure-analysis-services

When I try to process my Azure Cube, I get the following error:

```
{
    "statusCode": 409,
    "headers": {
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
        "x-ms-root-activity-id": "6xxx82d1-xxxx-4613-9ca5-xxxxxxxxxx",
        "x-ms-current-utc-date": "3/5/2019 4:00:25 PM",
        "x-ms-xmlaerror-extended": "Internal error AsyncOperationConflictException_Message1.CUBENAME",
        "Date": "Tue, 05 Mar 2019 16:00:26 GMT",
        "Server": "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
        "Content-Length": "296",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    "body": {
        "code": "Conflict",
        "subCode": 1,
        "message": "Internal error AsyncOperationConflictException_Message1.CUBENAME",
        "timeStamp": "2019-03-05T16:00:26.2644538Z",
        "httpStatusCode": 409,
        "details": [
            {
                "code": "RootActivityId",
                "message": "6xxx82d1-f39e-xxxx-9ca5-xxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            {
                "code": "Param1",
                "message": "inspire"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

A brief explanation:
I try to process my cube in logic apps. In the following figure in step 1 I scale out my Azure AS, then in step 2 set the parameter and in step 3 I get the error:
[image]

Do you have any idea why I get this error?

Comment: This article may apply if you are doing a refresh:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-async-refresh#post-refreshes. From the doc, "Only one refresh operation is accepted at a time for a model. If there's a current running refresh operation and another is submitted, the 409 Conflict HTTP status code is returned."

Comment: What should I do to avoid this error?

Comment: Can you delete the in-progress refresh (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-async-refresh#delete-refreshesrefreshid) and retry?

Comment: but how to catch refreshid on air in logic apps?is it possible?

Comment: Try using an API tool like Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) to GET the refreshId in-progress, then DELETE it. You could connect the API calls and responses using a Logic App, but that'd be more difficult.